# Error EntityNotFound from store layer Redis Golang

Tags: go, error-handling, redis

I have a golang Project that implements `redis` as it's backend store. In the `Get` method of the store layer, I want to check if an entity is existing or not. If the entity is existing i will return it else i have two cases :

- Error `EntityNotFound`
- DB Error

I am only able to return the DB Error. How can i return the entity not found error. Like what's the condition for checking in `redis`.

Help Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a key lookup the Redis client will return an error if the key does not exist. You can check if that error is equal to `redis.Nil`, which indicates that the key was not found.

```golang
value, err = client.Get(ctx, key)
if errors.Is(err, redis.Nil) {
  return EntityNotFound
} else if err != nil {
  // Some other error
  return err
}
```